# Quadrilateral Detection & Pose Estimation

Tags: opengl, opencv, hsv, homography

How can i estimate the pose of a quadrilateral using OpenCV.
I only need to detect a Rectangle on the frame..not all the quadrilaterals on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Yes with correspondences between the source points (real world points) and destination points (image points), you can calculate homography. All you need to do is find the corners of a rectangular cardboard in the image and using the real world points, you can find homography.

There is already a function for it in opencv. Look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) for more details.